# pyaudio works, but output plays less than actual time

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I'm new to python programming.
I'm dealing with a script to play a simple tone using pyaudio. The following script is supposed to play a simple 1-second tone of 500 Hz. I do hear something, but I don't hear it same as in MATLAB (which works perfectly) and more importantly, it's not played for 1 second, but something around 200 ms.

```py
import numpy as np
import pyaudio

fs = 44100
T = 1
N = T*fs
t = np.array(range(N))/fs
f = 500
sig = 0.5*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream= p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
               channels=1,
               rate=fs,
               output=True)

stream.write(sig)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

I've also tried introducing pause between writing on the stream and stopping the stream. Didn't work.
Any idea where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you're asking.

```
import pyaudio
from math import pi
import numpy as np

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, channels=1, rate=44100, output=1,)


def make_wave(frequency, length, sample_rate=44100):
    length = int(length * sample_rate)
    factor = float(frequency) * (pi * 2) / sample_rate
    waveform = np.sin(np.arange(length) * factor)

    return waveform


wave = make_wave(500, 1)

stream.write(wave.astype(np.float32).tostring())
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! thanks. Still one question: why do we need `.tostring()`. My script did not work exactly because this `.tostring()` was missing.